# Monitor Screen Shaking

Tags: display

Any idea how's this happen and is there a chance I fix it myself?
The monitor is the problem, I tried with another monitor and it went flawlessly.

And for additional information, it's LG 20M38

Here's the [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FJXs4JTAXLJh5vc58iegZ2tnCH0mRJLt)

Comment: The video link is dead.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for reporting

Comment: Short in the cable or the port itself?  Have you tried one of the ports you aren't using or a different cable?

Comment: Yes I tried it zillion times. As I said, the problem is the monitor.